# Position multiple div elements around the circle like clock

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to position elements around the circle like we usually have on an analogue clock. I have set the angles for every element now task is to align it around the circle. The starting point of placing element would be `120deg` The following image is kind of expected result.

[image]

This is what I have written so far. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqbjd91L/)

But I am not able to think further at this point. From CSS aspect I think we need position `absolute` and `right` and `bottom` properties but the values of `bottom` and `right` would be calculated based on some algorithm.

```js
var numberOfElement = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30];
var initialRender = numberOfElement.slice(0, 13);

function renderAngle(data) {
  var angles = [120];
  data.forEach(function(item, index) {
    angles.push(angles[index] + 20);
  })
  return angles;
}

function generateHtml() {
  var html = '';
  var angles = renderAngle(initialRender);
  var shapeType = 1;
  angles.forEach(function(item, index) {
    html += '<div class="shape-' + shapeType + '" style="transform:rotate(' + item + 'deg)"> ' + item + ' </div>';
    shapeType++;
    if (shapeType > 9) {
      shapeType = 1;
    }
  })
  document.querySelector('.circle').innerHTML = html;
  console.log('item', html)
}
generateHtml()
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
}

.circle {
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.shape-1 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green
}

.shape-2 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green
}

.shape-3 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green
}

.shape-4 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green
}

.shape-5 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green
}

.shape-6 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green
}

.shape-7 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green
}

.shape-8 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green
}

.shape-9 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green
}


.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 3em !important; }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="circle">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Carlos you need to modify the shape class to set the correct left and top attributes and set the position also

Comment: You can check the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366168/writing-a-program-in-which-theres-a-picture-rotating-around-a-circle?rq=1

Comment: @mbadeveloper I got your point. That is the one way of doing it. but it kind of doing it manually. But if new element is being added to circle then I have to set it CSS class

Comment: If you check the question I added in the comment they use                     left= x + points[i][0]; top= y + points[i][1]; to calculate the new position. Its like that you calculate the angle to rotate the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok…

I removed the multiple `.shapeX` classes in the JS and CSS to only use one (`.shapes`), as well as the `shapeType` variable. This was only meant to make the snippet easier.
You may want to add them back.

… Then, I played a little with your code and ended up with this:
(See comments in my code for details)

```js
var numberOfElement = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30];
var initialRender = numberOfElement.slice(0, 17); // TAKIT: Modified to test

function renderAngle(data) {
  var angles = [120];
  data.forEach(function(item, index) {
    angles.push((angles[index] + 20) % 360);      // TAKIT: Added modulo
  })
  return angles;
}

function generateHtml() {
  var html = '';
  var angles = renderAngle(initialRender);
  angles.forEach(function(item, index) {
    // TAKIT: Added use of a CSS var here, so all the CSS is in the CSS!
    html += '<div class="shapes' + '" style="--deg:' + item + 'deg;">' + item + '</div>';
  });
  document.querySelector('.circle').innerHTML = html; // TAKIT: Moved it here, after the loop
}

generateHtml();
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px; /* TAKIT: reduced only for snippet */
}

.circle {
  background: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.shapes {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px); /* TAKIT: position at center, 25px is half the height */
  left: calc(50% - 3px); /* TAKIT: position at center, 3px is half the width */
  width: 6px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  /* TAKIT: Using CSS var is cool for the rotation
            Using translate here to shift it from the center */
  transform: rotate(var(--deg)) translate(-50%, 104px);
  /* TAKIT: 104px in translate means 4px of margin between circle and shapes */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

And, the old way, without CSS variable, use it *only if needed*:

```
  angles.forEach(function(item, index) {
    // TAKIT: Without CSS var… I'm sad.
    html += '<div class="shapes' + '" style="transform: rotate(' + item + 'deg) translate(0, 100px);"> ' + item + ' </div>';
  });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice! It's not the layout the OP wants but big like on the usage of css variables this way. Also, keep attention of the [browsers support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)

Comment: very nice! With a tiny change in your code you can support IE too. While, I also like cool things (), it will be better if you, at least, show the "old" way for IE supporting..

Comment: Wow!!. You did it with CSS!.

Comment: @Carlos Glad to help! Were the multiple classes only meant to achieve this? (I'll update the text in my answer according to your answer here. :))

Comment: @TakitIsy There can be a different shape in the terms of height and width. That is why I use different classes. Although I did not mention this in my question as I was only concern about the position of element

Comment: @Carlos Ok, nice. :) I suggest you to keep the `.shapes` class for positioning (with `position` and `transform` properties), and add another `.shapeX` with all the other properties.